# Line breaks in facebook story attachments

Tags: facebook, attachment, facebook-opengraph, caption, facebook-stream-story

I am currently facing a problem on facebook and the new open graph stuff. I set up an application that allows for posting stories with a custom action and a custom type (search / real estate).

In the story attachment configuration dialog (layout 'item') I tried to add captions other than the one that is displayed by default. It is working quite well expect for the fact that the preview and actual post differ in layout. The preview shows each caption on a new line, while the actual post shows all captions merged into one line without line breaks. I wonder if this is the desired behaviour. At least I'd like to have them on seperate lines.

The data to be shown in the story is derived from the OG meta tags that are included in the referenced webpage. Thus I am not sure if the solutions discussed on stackoverflow (e.g. putting center tags in between, inserting line feeds etc.) works here.

Just as an additional information: I am using Spring Social to post the story.

I hope anyone has an idea how to show the captions in seperate line in actual posted stories.

Thanks...

**EDIT**

[image: Story - Edit Attachments Dialog]
***Story - Edit Attachments Dialog***

[image: Story - Preview One To One]
***Story - Preview / Configuration***

[image: Story - Actual Post]

***Story - Actual Post***

I think it doesn't matter how the OG meta tags are defined in the webpage as for the use case shown here, I used constant strings and no object/action properties.

Using html tags or line feeds in the caption input fields does not affect the layout, as all the input is escaped.

I hope this gives you better insight to what I tried to explain first.

Comment: Can you show the current codes ?

Comment: I've the same problem. But on my stories the title and captions are under the image - looks strange and broken too, because there's no linebreak or space between caption 1 and caption 2
Here's the bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/313772212098558

Answer (score 0):

To make the captions dynamic you have to add curly braces : example :

```
by {}
```

{} will show a drop down with your custom objects and you can use your objects to make captions dynamic.

However there is a huge limitation of bringing these captions into new lines.